# Problem with line filling in a list plot

Tags: plotting, filling

In the following plot,

1. why is there some non connected dots,
2. why the colors are'nt true.

```
elec = {66.`, 600.`, 200.`, 126.`, 68.`, 52.`, 114.`, 229.`, 71.`, 
   141.`, 39.`, 119.`, 224.`, 121.`, 457.`, 53.`, 167.`, 82.`, 304.`, 
   138.`, 235.`, 154.`, 181.`, 129.`, 1411.`, 134.`, 164.`, 126.`, 
   369.`, 130.`, 179.`, 100.`, 192.`, 472.`, 80.`};
sieg = {2.`, 7.`, 3.`, 2.`, 2.`, 2.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 2.`, 1.`, 2.`, 
   3.`, 2.`, 5.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 4.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 16.`, 
   2.`, 2.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 3.`, 2.`, 3.`, 5.`, 2.`};
r = sieg/elec
m = Mean[r]
mm = Table[m, {i, 36}];
s = StandardDeviation[r]
g1 = ListPlot[{sieg/elec, mm}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];
g2 = Plot[ {m, m + s, m - s, m + 2 s, m - 2 s}, {x, 0, 36}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {5}, 1 -> {4}, 1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}, 
   FillingStyle -> {{Opacity[.001], LightYellow}, 
     LightBlue, {Opacity[.001], Red}}];
Show[g2, g1]
```

[image]

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All` to `g1`. Try with `1 -> {5, Directive[Opacity[.001], LightYellow]}` for `Filling`, also opacity `0.001` means this is almost transparent.

Comment: The first info works but for  g2 = Plot[ {m, m + s, m - s, m + 2 s, m - 2 s}, {x, 0, 35}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2, Directive[Opacity[.3], LightYellow]}, 
     1 -> {3, Directive[Opacity[.3], LightRed]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, .04}]; the fill is not in the good direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[{m, m + s, m - s, m + 2 s, m - 2 s}, {x, 0, 35}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Opacity[.3, Yellow]},  1 -> {{3}, Opacity[.3, Yellow]}, 
     2 -> {{4}, Opacity[.3, Red]}, 3 -> {{5}, Opacity[.3, Red]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, .04},
 Epilog -> ListPlot[{sieg/elec, mm}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotRange -> All][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would never have thought that one can use ListPlot in an Epilog. Thanks.